# CakePHP conditions clause on associations when using Model::find()

Tags: cakephp

I just confused because of a `find()` result. This is my configurations:

First, users can have different `User.role` values: `student`, `admin`, and some others.

```
// Book
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
        'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'student')
     );
);
```

When I chain Models like `$this->Book->Student->find('list');` I was expecting to get only users whose role are `'student'`, but instead, it gets all users. What is going on here, what is `conditions` for on association definition, where can it and cannot be used. Any lead would help, thanks.

**PS: I am aware that I could put conditions on `find()`, that's not the issue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between associated data and accessing an associated model object. If you access $this->Book->Student you're accessing the Student model and work in it's scope. The conditions in the defined associations work only in the context of the accessed object.

So if you do a find on the Book and list the students for that book:

```
$this->Book->find('first', array('contain' => array('Student'));
```

Your code will work correctly. It will find the book plus the first user who has the role stundent. **BUT** your association is wrong then: It should be hasMany. because why would you filter a book by role if the book just belongsTo one student?

If you want to filter users by their role you can implement a query param that is checked in beforeFind(), pseudocode: if isset roleFilter then add contention to filter by that role from roleFilter.

Or, if you don't need to paginate just create a getStudents() method in the user model that will return a find('list') that has the conditions.

Or `Student extends User` and put the filter in the beforeFind() and use that model instead of the User model in your Book association.

If you want to filter on model level or per model I think the last one is a good option. Don't forget to set `$useTable` and `$name` or the inherited model will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

you have miss , inside your model.
try this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_id', //<------ miss
        'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'student')
     );
);
```

Yoi can debug your query to check what is the real query that you make.
Personally I have never use this approach, I prefer to use foreign key with another table for examples `Roles`and `User.role_id`.
Is better for me to use this approach to have more flexibility inside your app.
After I prefer to use a conditions where inside controller to check well the query, because in your way every query you search always for student role not for the other and can be a problem for the rest of role, because inside controller you see a find without conditions but it doesn't take right value because in your model there is a particular conditions.

For me the good way is to create a new table, use foreign key and where conditions inside action of the controller to view well what are you doing.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo on my post, the code is fine. Now that I researched a little bit, could it be that model chaining (i.e `$this->Book->Student->find()`) is not the same as $this->Book->find() containing Student?  maybe I have the wrong idea of model chaining

Comment: yes is the same but I advise you t put the where conditions in the controller not in the model @ChristopherFrancisco

Answer (score 0):

For **default** all relations are "**left join**", you must set the parameter "**type**" with "**inner**" value

```
// Book
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
        'conditions' => array('Student.role' => 'student'), // <-- Fix That (field name)
        'type' => 'inner', // <-- add that
     );
);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. Do these relationship work when model chaining or only for itself? maybe that's the problem, since the SQL Log doesn't say nor LEFT JOIN nor INNER JOIN.

Comment: That work with both. If you only want get the students you must add the conditions  in your find method, because that relation it's for all the model.